# Oracle - find N neighbors (points) of a point within a radio

Tags: oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial, spatial-query

I have this table, there it goes a sample output to show that it is a point

```
select SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(geo) 
from places 
where id=1
_______________________________________________________

POINT (-88.706148 32.374127)
```

Given a point (i.e. latitude: 32.378097, longitude:-88.709356) I need to get the N neighbors that are around that point in a radio distance of 1 kilometer (0.6 miles)

So far I have this

```
SELECT id, description, latitude, longitude, SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) dist  
FROM places P 
WHERE sdo_nn (geoloc,  MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(1, 8307, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE( -88.709356 , 32.378097, NULL), NULL, NULL), 'distance=1 unit=KM', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

But, that query does not return points from places that are near, like 400 meters

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: That should work fine: the syntax is correct. What exact result do you get ? And can you share some sample data ?

Answer (score 1):

That works fine with my tests. It returns all the places that are less than 1 km from your origin point. Note that you should use the proper geometry type for 2D points (i.e. 2001 instead of 1):

```
SELECT id, description, latitude, longitude, SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) dist  
FROM places P 
WHERE sdo_nn (geoloc, SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(-88.709356, 32.378097, NULL), NULL, NULL), 'distance=1 unit=KM', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

For example:

```
select id, city, state_abrv, SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) dist 
from us_cities 
where sdo_nn(location, SDO_GEOMETRY(1, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(-88.709356, 32.378097, NULL), NULL, NULL), 'distance=300 unit=KM', 1) = 'TRUE';

        ID CITY                 STATE_       DIST
---------- -------------------- ------ ----------
        78 Jackson              MS      141.17698
        79 Mobile               AL     197.555367
        60 Birmingham           AL     219.435603
        86 Montgomery           AL     228.247059
        25 New Orleans          LA     281.561957

5 rows selected.
```

Just to be clear: the goal of the `SDO_NN` operator is to return the **closest** places to an origin, no matter the distance, and considering any other predicates. 
It is designed to answer questions like: *"find me all the nearest restaurants of type 'chinese' that are open today, serve Szechuan cuisine and take reservations"*

The **distance** limit is there to remove unrealistic answers - like those restaurants that meet all critieria but are 100km away.

Note that the distance returned by SDO_NN_DISTANCE is expressed in the unit you choose, i.e. kilometers. If you want a result in miles, then just do:

```
SELECT id, description, latitude, longitude, SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) dist  
FROM places P 
WHERE sdo_nn (geoloc, SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(-88.709356, 32.378097, NULL), NULL, NULL), 'distance=0.6 unit=mile', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

For example:

```
select id, city, state_abrv, SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) dist 
from us_cities 
where sdo_nn(location, SDO_GEOMETRY(1, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE( -88.709356 , 32.378097, NULL), NULL, NULL), 'distance=186.41 unit=mile', 1) = 'TRUE';

        ID CITY                 STATE_       DIST
---------- -------------------- ------ ----------
        78 Jackson              MS     87.7233084
        79 Mobile               AL     122.755214
        60 Birmingham           AL     136.350962
        86 Montgomery           AL     141.826147
        25 New Orleans          LA     174.954489

5 rows selected.
```

If all you want is to search for places within a radius, then use the `SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE` operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to to use degrees to radians and  radians to degrees..

```
> SELECT * FROM ( SELECT zip, primary_city, state,
>        latitude, longitude, distance   FROM (  SELECT z.zip, z.primary_city, z.state,
>         z.latitude, z.longitude,
>         p.radius,
>         p.distance_unit
>             * rad2deg * (ACOS(COS(deg2rad * (p.latpoint))
>                             * COS(deg2rad * (z.latitude))
>                             * COS(deg2rad * (p.longpoint - z.longitude))
>                             + SIN(deg2rad * (p.latpoint))
>                             * SIN(deg2rad * (z.latitude)))) AS distance   FROM zip z   JOIN (
>         SELECT  42.81  AS latpoint,    -70.81 AS longpoint,
>                 50.0 AS radius,        111.045 AS distance_unit,
>                 57.2957795 AS rad2deg,
>                 0.0174532925 AS deg2rad
>           FROM  DUAL
>     ) p ON 1=1   WHERE z.latitude
>      BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
>          AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
>     AND z.longitude
>      BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(deg2rad * (p.latpoint))))
>          AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(deg2rad * (p.latpoint))))  )  WHERE distance <= radius  ORDER BY distance ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 20
```

source:
https://www.plumislandmedia.net/oracle/fast-nearest-location-finder-oracle/

Comment: There is absolutely no need to manually compute the distances. The distance is automatically computed by the sdo_nn operator and returned by the sdo_nn_distance() function.